# I am able to … VS I am good with …

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

Being none native speaker can be very difficult especially when we get to hear the natives use certain expression or words which are not familiar to us; we sometimes blindly follow them as we expect them to be correct in most cases:

Are both sentences to be considered gramatically the same?

Do you have any problem with Ivy?

I don’t have any problem with Ivy because…

1. I am good with Ivy
2. I am able to socialise with Ivy just great/good

Will number 1 not sound like ‘you and Ivy actually are good’ as in ‘Me and Ivy are good’? Is it grammatical to say so when it comes to academic prose: please enlighten me.

Will number 2 or something similar to its contruction will be prefered?

Comment: “I get along well with Ivy” is general and idiomatic—and not inappropriately informal or slangy.

Comment: "I am good with Ivy" sounds as though Ivy has some psychological problem which makes her difficult to look after or socialise with, and the speaker is claiming to be good at managing her difficult behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your context for a moment, these two idiomatic phrases are different, and it is a very important and useful distinction.

- "Able to" means you *can* do something.
- "Good with" means you have a *reasonable* degree of competency.

This is very useful in writing a resume, when you may want to note a degree of ability in something without overselling yourself as an expert; or where you want to imply some transferrable skill. For example, saying "I am *good with* computers" is very broad and suggests normal competency levels, but if you wanted to meet a particular qualification for a job specification you might have to say "I am able to" do [something specific].

---

In your context of being "good with" *someone*, there are some things to consider. When said of another adult, being "good with" someone can mean that you have a peaceful relationship with them. However, when said of someone *dependent* on you, such as a child or someone with special needs, it usually means that you are *good at dealing with them*. For example, being "good with" a child usually means that you are a good role model, that you are able to play with them and talk to them on a level they understand and appreciate.

"I am able to socialise with [someone] just great" is informal but grammatically fine and focus specifically on *socialising* rather than any of the other things that could be incorporated into being "good with" them. However, "just *good*" is not at all idiomatic.

Comment: I think it it also important to note that *Good With* more often means *Accepting Of*, especially when referring to things other than individuals.   For example, Person A: *I couldn't get plane tickets so we are travelling to Chicago by bus.*   Person B: *OK.  I'm good with the bus.*  *Good with* is also a very slangy usage with a meaning that changes based on context, whereas *able to* is quite standard.